# Secure ELMAH in Web API 2 project: Share Authorization code

Tags: asp.net-web-api, elmah

I am using ELMAH in a Web API 2 project. I wrote my own `IAuthenticationFilter` to authenticate against Atlassian's CROWD.
I want to secure ELMAH also against CROWD. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to make a secure Web API call that shows the most recent or the most common errors in your ELMAH data store?  If so, why not write those data-fetching calls and secure them with your custom filter the same way as your other API calls.

Comment: No, I don't want to access ELMAH via the Web API. I want to use the normal elmah UI but secure it and authenticate against crowd.

Comment: I see.  You want to hit /elmah.axd, but have it secured with your custom filter.  I don't see a way to do that with the built in ELMAH security options, which are for users and roles, and I'm not sure if CROWD provides that.

Comment: Not necessarily with my custom filter. I do have a Crowd MembershipProvider as well, but honestly, I simply don't know how to configure it so that it only applies to the ELMAH route and not to my web api controllers.

Comment: How about something in the web.config like `<location path="elmah.axd"><system.web><membership defaultProvider="CrowdMembershipProvider">more Crowd stuff here?...</membership><authorization><allow roles="CrowdProviderRole"/><deny users="*"/></authorization></system.web></location>'

Comment: I actually already tried that, but it fails with " It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Comment: And configuring this on the application level obviously results in the whole web api using that membership provider

Comment: Maybe `<membership>` is colliding between the machine and web configs. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b9hw62f(v=vs.100).aspx, it looks like you need to `<remove>` or `<clear/>` the machine.config provider `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` and `<add>` your Crowd one.

Comment: I did that. The problem is that this tag can't exist below a location tag. It needs to be application global. I think I will stop investing time here now and simply host the elmah viewer in an own application. Thanks for your efforts! :-)